# Default sketch working but arduino is not recognizing

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an arduino UNO and when I connected the device through the USB to the PC (with windows 7 64 bit),

The default blinking sketch, which comes shipped with it, is working,

but the device recognition sound is not playing.

and the device driver installation dialog never appeared and no arduino entry in the device manager.

And when I tried to upload a successfully compiled sketch from the ide 1.8.4 ,

It just says, 'problem uploading to board'
More verbosely, **' avrdude: can't open device""\.\COM1": the system cannot find the file specified'**

The device is getting power and running the sketch,
But device is not recognized, maybe it is connected charge only, can I install the drivers manually?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it real or a copy?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino or a cheap clone from eBay or Amazon?

Comment: I got it from a local electronic parts store so it is a copy.

Comment: Then you need to identify what usb interface chip it uses and install the right drivers for it, and make sure that your cable is working right.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help but how to identify it?  I'm new to arduino

Comment: By reading the text on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64372/discussion-between-practronix512-and-majenko).

Comment: Sorry, can't chat now. Just read the text on the USB interface chip. That's the one closest to the usb socket, obviously.

Comment: Chip says: MEGA16U2

Comment: Then you have a (potentially) genuine Arduino Uno R3. Installing the IDE should install the drivers for you - otherwise the drivers are included in the ZIP version of the IDE for you to manually install. So next is to try a different  USB cable. Some cables only have power wires in them and no data, which may be what you have there.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange.  Please take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  Generally the IDE will only offer ports that will work.

Comment: I tried a new cable but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hahaha! I figured it out! The USB connector on the board's side was loose connected! It didn't felt like more pressable & when I pressed it enough, it firmly fitted.

When it loose connected, the board connects power only.

The drivers were installed automatically & it showed under COM6. I've got sketches running in no time.
I' ve tried a lot of knight rider patterns with a bunch of RGB LEDs then ;-)

Thank you @Majenko and the arduino stack exchage for your kind replies.